# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value to a data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a query that I'm attempting to check the `scode` column for a range of code numbers.  The problem is the `scode` column includes some nvarchar characters, and errors when it finds them.

How can I run the following query, without returning errors.

```
SELECT dtExpires, dtFirst
FROM Customers
WHERE (scode BETWEEN 10 AND 100) OR
      (scode BETWEEN 500 AND 600)
```

Error I'm receiving:

> *Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value to a data type int*

Comment: what is the data type of scode ? Seems nvachar

Comment: Stop storing numbers in nvarchar columns!

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have any say over that.  I'm just simply running queries on the data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can't FIX THE DATA TYPE which is really what you SHOULD be doing...

The only reliable way to short-circuit is to stuff filtered results into a #temp table. Otherwise you have no control over order of evaluation. Even if you use a subquery or CTE to filter rows where `ISNUMERIC() = 1` "first", SQL Server might evaluate the `BETWEEN` conditional first, and still fail with the same error. This may not *always* happen, but this is the only way to guarantee you avoid it:

```
SELECT dtExpires, dtFirst, scode
INTO #t
FROM dbo.Customers
WHERE scode NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'; -- this assumes no decimals allowed

SELECT dtExpires, dtFirst
FROM #t
WHERE (scode BETWEEN 10  AND 100) 
   OR (scode BETWEEN 500 AND 600);

DROP TABLE #t;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your ultimate problem here is that you are storing these number values as `nvarchar`. This is problematic for several reasons first of is speed. There are tons of great documents and answers out there showing this is the case many of them on this very [Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284297/sql-server-int-vs-nvarchar-comparison-on-performance).

Integer values are smaller than character strings you can fit much more per page than you can with `nvarchar` and mathematics are more easily done on integers. Try a little experiment go to [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and enter your table and give it some values and run your query. Then try changing that column to an integer value and running the same query not only will it run faster but your current `SELECT` statement will run properly. If you ever need to join on this information and integer will me much faster as well.

I'm not entirely sure as to weather or not you have the power to do this or not but it will certainly fix your problem and improve your database performance as well.

Comment: I agree with most except for the speed. Integrity is more important. And avoiding problems like the current one that OP faces.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use something like

```
SELECT        dtExpires, dtFirst
FROM            Customers
WHERE        ( cast(fnRemoveNonNumericCharacters(scode) as int) BETWEEN 10 AND 100) OR
                     (cast(fnRemoveNonNumericCharacters(scode) as int)BETWEEN 500 AND 600)
```

where the function is :

```
CREATE Function [fnRemoveNonNumericCharacters](@strText VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @strText = STUFF(@strText, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText), 1, '')
    END
    RETURN @strText
END
```

or if you want to exclude those entries where scode is not numeric make also a bool returning function that will tell you if it has non numeric chars and put it in the where clause.

also a way to solve this might be: (inspired a lil bit by Aron

```
SELECT        dtExpires, dtFirst
FROM            Customers
WHERE        (( case when scode LIKE '%[^0-9]%' then 0 else scode end BETWEEN 10 AND 100) OR
                     (case when scode LIKE '%[^0-9]%' then 0 else scode end BETWEEN 500 AND 600))
and scode not like '%[^0-9]%'
```

Comment: You can't filter out non-numerics in the where clause because you can't control the order of evaluation. Even if you do `SELECT FROM (SELECT ... WHERE ISNUMERIC()=1) x WHERE ` it might evaluate the outer where clause first and still fail.

Comment: Also adding this function is going to be extremely slow, and might not return the desired results. Is `1x2` which gets changed to `12` really supposed to come back between 10 and 100?

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes .. but I said .. also to add another function, it's either the first or both (not to get the error you are talking about)
Slow I admit .. it might be slow if you check on too many rows without other filters ..

Comment: My point was adding a where clause to exclude non-numeric scode values may seem like a logical thing to do, but it won't necessarily do that first - it might try to evaluate the BETWEEN filter first. So how does it help?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I understood what you meant. If both functions are used, then the query will filter but the non numeric clause and also will not give error in the between. In this case you get a list with what you need without errors.

Comment: And what about my point that just stripping non-numeric characters from, say, `xxxyun7ttgh5`, which yields `75`, does not necessarily mean the OP *wants* `75` in the result. Do you not think that's a problem?

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes .. that is why I said they could be filtered out by another where clause ..

Comment: I never try .. do not have time .. but if you were talking about the not I already changed it ..

Comment: You don't have time to test code you're posting as an answer? So everyone who wants to try your code can waste their time testing it? That seems kind of selfish doesn't it, given how much time you've spent arguing with me about your "solution"?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I didn't argue, and my solution is sound :). Trying to explain to someone why something works is not really arguing.