# Will joining on integer be quicker than joining on nvarchar?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Does it have a significant impact on performance if you use integer key columns instead of nvarchar(20) ? I assume that all fields used in the joins have been indexed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at the following post.

[JOIN ON varchar VS join on int](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/986a3009-bb5b-4acc-9f6a-772f5dbd698f/join-on-varchar-vs-join-on-int)

Basically the int is the best option.

Answer (score 7):

The `INT` should be faster than `NVARCHAR(20)` because an `INT` is only 4 bytes, so you can hold more indexes/data in memory at one time. You should always try to use the smallest data type practical for all columns.

Answer (score 0):

It is faster to use an `integer` because an integer is easily stored in binary, `1`'s and `0`'s, computers understand these a lot better than they do characters of any language.  `NVARCHAR`'s have to be converted into much larger binary types by the DBMS, `NVARCHAR(20)` and `INT` are our examples.  An integer holds 4 bytes of data, and the `NVARCHAR(20)` [holds up to 42 bytes of data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx), which means that an index of either of these would be completely different from each other.  An index of the variable character type would have at the most 38 bytes more data to index, if you need all those extra indexes then it would make sense, but an integer already holds so many possible values.

in other words the indexing and searching through the `INT` column would be faster because there is less information for the database to look through.

please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3284368/1214743), which backs up my claim.  This link talks about pages of indexing.

Comment: FYI, NVARCHAR(20) holds up to 40 bytes. Also, if someone is storing only "AB" in the field, those 2 characters will only take up 4 bytes.

Comment: according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) it is actually 42 bytes for a `NVARCHAR(20)` if you enter all 20 characters, @srutzky.

Comment: Yes, there are an extra 2 bytes per each variable-length field, and an extra 2 bytes just for having _any_ variable length fields in the first place. While important, those details pertain to overall row size and not so much the specific value that is being compared when using the index.

Comment: regardless of the extra 2 bytes, an `INT` is a better key/index than a `NVARCHAR` which wasn't meant for indexing in the first place.

Comment: I completely agree with `INT` being better for JOINs (the original Question) :-).  I was just trying to help correct the info being presented. But I wouldn't go so far as to say that string fields shouldn't be indexed, just not JOINed on.

Comment: if you have the choice, between indexing `NVARCHAR` and `INT` which would you choose?  thank you for the correction, I appreciate it.

Comment: If I have a choice then 99% of the time I would choose `INT`. Depending on circumstances I might choose `NVARCHAR`, but I would use a binary collation (i.e. `Latin1_General_100_BIN2`) so that the speed was about the same. BUT, I don't have a choice when looking up someone's LastName ;-). This is why I specified that I would always choose INT (or even BIGINT) for JOINs, because you nearly always do have a choice when it comes to JOINs since we can choose how we model the data. But not so much for the data points that we are storing. PS. if I sound argumentative, then that is not the intention.